# running phpwebsocket server .php

Tags: php, websocket

I am playing around with phpwebsocket. I got the code from http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/. the implementation is that I have to run the server.php using command line which starts the socket linstening on a port. but I am wondering if I upload the script to my blog server(one.com), how  can I start the server.php without command line?

thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting it on the command-line is the appropriate mechanism.

You *could* run it through a webserver, but only by hacking around with the default lifetime of scripts, and it's not how PHP server scripts are designed to be run.

Comment: Actually there's lots of ways to get a daemon running without shell access - but the hosting company will have blocked shell access because they don't want you running daemons.

Comment: @symcbean: Then you're SOL. Trying to run a daemon when you're prohibited from running daemons seems like a fool's errand. Get a proper server.

Answer (score 2):

To use WebSocket you need a process which is listing to specific WebSocket port. You need to start using command line. By using this please make sure that you have enough error catching mechanism in place in php script. So it is better to use a shell script which can restart the server if any major error occures.

http://www.techzonemind.com/php-websocket-library-two-way-real-time-communication/

I have developed a library to solve the issue. Include both client(JavaScript) and server (PHP). Also included shell script(.sh) to start the php process.